# Elementary Inequality question

Tags: inequality

this might be a stupid question, but I wanted to know that if a,b,c are positive reals and
$$ab+bc+ca\geq 3$$
Can we say that 
$$3 \sqrt[3]{(abc)^2} \geq 3$$
By applying am-gm? I'm confused about whether we can do this or not. I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain.

Comment: Well, you know that the arithmetic mean is bigger than 1, and that the geometric mean is less than the arithmetic mean, so I think there is a step missing to also conclude that the geometric mean is bigger than 1.

Comment: Please don't downvote, I really want to know in which cases it's possible

Comment: That wasn't me, I don't know who did that. =(

Comment: @user546996 Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to provide more context in your question.  How did you hypothesize that the first inequality might lead to the second?  Can you show the work you did to get there?  If not, then provide the entire question you're asking about.

Comment: @Andreas well put, but I think in the light of this question, we should include a,b,c > 0, but op didnt say so btw.

Comment: Yeah, it was specified that a,b,c are positive reals

Comment: counterexample is: Consider  $a = 10^{-10}$, $b=c=2$, then the first inequality holds and the second doesn't.

Comment: Then that's the kind of info you need to edit your post to include.  This is not a "do my work for me" and "guess what I mean" site.

Comment: Yes also you may have counterexample $a=1.5$ and $b=c=0.8$, though andreas was quick on example! $ab+bc+ca = 3.04$ but $abc = 0.96$

Comment: If it were $ab+bc+ca\le 3$, then:
$3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}\le 3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe we cannot arrive at this conclusion, because of the following counterexample:

Let $a=3$, $b=1-\epsilon$, and $c=\frac{1}{3}$. Then $ab+bc+ca\geq 4-3\epsilon\geq 3$, but $3(abc)^{2/3}<3$.

So for any sufficiently small $\epsilon$ our conclusion doesn't hold.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot